# System boots, but linux highly unstable and slow after CPU upgrade

Tags: linux, boot, debian, cpu

I have a HP IPM41-D3 from part of a OEM system. I was recently contacted by a friend offering a modded Xeon X5460 (LGA 771 to LGA775 pin swapped). He also helped me with the BIOS update and everything. However when I try to boot Debian with the new chip the process is extremely slow. It takes almost 5 mins to complete the kernel part before even getting a "Welcome to Debian..." message. That too with a lot of kernel panic and errors such as "TSC unstable" (see attached screenshots).

The system boots fine when I put in the older E5500 (original processor) and boots into linux in less than 10secs with no error.

I've tried reseatting the CPU, checking pins, and cleaning it however none of it help. What could be the issue here?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7Tc.jpg)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5RXu.jpg)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because author has withdrawn it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it describes a problem that can't be reproduced, and went away without any explanation that could help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was being caused by some setting in the advanced BIOS menu. I disabled all of them  and it worked fine. I tried to narrow it down to which setting it was but couldn't one-by-one I enabled them all and it ran fine again. Weird. Would appriciate if someone could give an explaination in the comments.

Marking this question as closed when possible.

EDIT 1: I figured out part of the issue. It was by the power-saving features of the CPU not playing well with the motherboard. Disabling them and rebooting seemed to help, however turning them back on later seemed fine as well and did not cause any issues.